# Combine CSS selector with ::after selector

Tags: html, css

I'm using a program in which users can change the color of the text. I want to change the color of my (custom) list-style based on the color of the text. I currently got the following code, but it doesn't work. I don't understand why. I hope someone can help.

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li::after {
  content '>';
}

li font[color="#dc1478"]~ ::after {
  color: #dc1478;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <font color="#005392">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</font>
    <font color="#dc1478"> blablasls</font>
    ::after
  </li>
</ul>
```

When is use the selectors sepertly from each other they work, but combined they don't.

`font[color="#dc1478"]` and `::after`

Comment: `:after` isn't a real element. You can only access it through its parent.

Comment: The [`<font>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) was deprecated in HTML 4.01, it should not be used at this point.

Answer (score 0):

your problem:

```
li::after {
 content '>';
}
```

==>

```
li::after {
 content: '>';
 color: #dc1478;
}
```

Comment: The color can change based on the users input. So this isn't an option.